# Publisher not picking up template changes

Tags: 2011, publishing, templating

I had a problem with the `Default Finish Actions` TBB containing the wrong namespace for some of the Parameter Schemas it referenced (but didn't use).  This was causing the publishing of items (Pages and Components) that used the TBB to fail:

```xml
  <TemplateInvocation>
    <Template xlink:href="tcm:9-378-2048" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="Convert Xml to Html" />
    <TemplateParameters>
      <Parameters xmlns="uuid:1129c935-725b-4c65-a38e-161ce749f2f1" />
    </TemplateParameters>
  </TemplateInvocation>
```

As the parameters were not being used, I removed the reference from the `Default Finish Actions` TBB:

```xml
  <TemplateInvocation>
    <Template xlink:href="tcm:9-378-2048" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="Convert Xml to Html" />
  </TemplateInvocation>
```

This appeared to fix the problem and I was able to preview the pages and run them through Template Builder.  However, when I came to publish the page, it failed with the same error as before in the publish transaction:

> Unexpected namespace URI: uuid:1129c935-725b-4c65-a38e-161ce749f2f1.
>   Expecting: uuid:faf6fb43-0c5b-4459-be1c-46c8842ad289.

Remembering that [the Publisher caches some of the templating code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261822/sdl-tridion-content-publishing-against-old-versions-of-templates), I restarted the Publisher and Transport services on the Publisher server.  (The Publisher is located on a separate server than the Content Manger install.)  This did not fix the problem and I was still getting the same publishing error.

Following this I've restarted the Publisher server - and I am still getting the same error.

I have enabled logging for the Publisher (in the Snap-in) and I'm getting the following message in the logs:

> 15/03/2013 09:39:24 <5056> Storage location:
>   c:\Temp\tcm_0-397559-66560.Content\
>
> 15/03/2013 09:39:25 <5056> Using resolver
>   [Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving.PageResolver]
>
> 15/03/2013 09:39:25 <5056> Resolving the pages [tcm:53-127413-64] took
>   00:00:00.1104738
>
> 15/03/2013 09:39:25 <5056> Page tcm:53-127413-64 resolved to 1 items.
>   Resolving took: 00:00:00.1907868
>
> 15/03/2013 09:39:25 <5056> Rendering item [tcm:53-127413-64] 'Index'
>   with template [tcm:53-2532-128] 'PT01 Landing Page' in publication
>   target [tcm:0-5-65537] 'Training Staging'
>
> 15/03/2013 09:39:32 <5056> Rendering item [tcm:53-21778] 'About us -
>   Content' with template [tcm:53-2430-32] 'CP17_ContentBlock_CT' in
>   publication target [tcm:0-5-65537] 'Training Staging'
>
> 15/03/2013 09:39:39 <5056> Rendering of item [tcm:53-127413-64]
>   'Index' with template [tcm:53-2532-128] 'PT01 Landing Page' in
>   publication target [tcm:0-5-65537] 'Training Staging' failed
>
> 15/03/2013 09:39:39 <5056> Deleting the transport package.
>
> 15/03/2013 09:39:39 <5056> Updating the publish transaction with the
>   list of processed items
>
> 15/03/2013 09:39:39 <5056> Unexpected namespace URI:
>   uuid:1129c935-725b-4c65-a38e-161ce749f2f1. Expecting:
>   uuid:faf6fb43-0c5b-4459-be1c-46c8842ad289.

Unfortunately, this does not give me any more information that I had before!  Is there a way to increase the logging level so that I get more information?  (I think that this is in the TcmPublisher.exe.config, but I cannot see where to update it.)

Is the template cache stored on the file system somewhere? Or do I need to restart something on the CM machine maybe to pick up the changes?

Comment: Deleted my answer - was telling you to check the XML of the templates, but it seems you can preview. Have you restart the publisher(s)? But this type of thing should not be cached. Can you check if `CP17_ContentBlock_CT` still has the XML with the namespace? I had to do quite some template hunting recently with the same issue...

Comment: Although the main publishing issue is now fixed, I would welcome some input on increasing the logging level on the Publisher to get more information please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slightly embarrassing but it appears that the check-in of the `Default Finish Actions` TBB had not completed.

I was able to Preview the Page (and run it in Template Builder) because my update had saved, but it was failing to publish because this uses the last checked-in version.

As noted by Nuno, once checked-in, I did not have do anything with the Publisher (restart, etc.).

**Lessons learned (or reminded of) along the way:**

1. The Publisher caches some of the templating code
2. The publisher logging is turned on in the MMC Snap-in
3. I now know where else to look for `Unexpected Namespace URI` errors (as well as in content Schemas)
4. Always check that changes are checked-in!

Comment: In older versions (at least R5.3) we had to `Save & Close` (check-in) to even preview changes. So if a template worked in CME Preview, it'd work when publishing. Now we have the benefit of seeing changes without closing the template or TBBs, but have to remember to `Save & Close`. :-)

Comment: That must have been why I was confused ;-)

Comment: Don't be embarrassed. This kind of thing happens to every single person who spends time on anything as big and complex as Tridion. Some people are willing to take the chance of looking a bit stupid by asking about their issue in public. Being a member of the community is about more than showing up with the answer - hey that's always going to make you look good. Asking a question leaves you a bit vulnerable - which is why it's probably even a more valuable community activity than answering.

Comment: Thanks Dominic.  Yes, I agree that fostering a great community around Tridion is more important than protecting one's ego.  Rest assured that I will continue to raise any trivial questions that I have! Jon